# Clojure reduce function

Tags: clojure

I am trying to understand this function from clojuredocs.org:

```
;; Create a word frequency map out of a large string s.

;; `s` is a long string containing a lot of words :)
(reduce #(assoc %1 %2 (inc (%1 %2 0)))
    {}
    (re-seq #"\w+" s))

; (This can also be done using the `frequencies` function.)
```

I dont understand this part: (inc (%1 %2 0))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument (`%1` in the anonymous function) to the function passed to `reduce` is the accumulator, which is initally the empty map `{}` passed as the second argument to `reduce`. Maps are functions which lookup the value for the given key, returning the optional default if the key is not found e.g.

```
({"word" 1} "word") = 1
```

and

```
({"word" 1} "other" 0) = 0
```

so

```
(%1 %2 0)
```

looks up the count for the current word (second argument to the reducing function) in the accumulator map, returning 0 if the word has not been added yet. `inc` increments the current count, so

```
#(assoc %1 %2 (inc (%1 %2 0))
```

increments the count of the current word in the intermediate map, or sets it to 1 if this is the first time the word has been encountered.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an easier to read example of the same thing, not using anonymous function syntax:

```
(reduce
  (fn [acc elem]
    (assoc acc elem (inc (acc elem 0))))
  {}
  (re-seq #"\w+" "a dog a cat a dog a banana"))
=> {"a" 4, "dog" 2, "cat" 1, "banana" 1}
```

Here `acc` is the map we are building up, and `elem` is the current word. Let's break down `(inc (acc elem 0))`:

1. `inc` is going to increment the number returned from the inner expression
2. `(acc elem 0)` is going to `get` the current number from the `acc` map for the word `elem`, and if there is no number there it'll return `0`.  This is short for `(get acc elem 0)` -- maps are functions too and behave like the `get` function.

You can also achieve the same effect as `(assoc acc elem (inc (acc elem 0)))` with `(update acc elem (fnil inc 0))`.

The same logic applies when you replace the reduce function with an anonymous syntax using numbered arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The code you are asking about is essentially [that of the standard `frequencies` function](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L7123) with [transients](https://clojure.org/reference/transients) removed:

```
(defn frequencies [coll]
   (reduce
     (fn [counts x] (assoc counts x (inc (get counts x 0))))
     {}
     coll))
```

This

- uses a `fn` form instead of an [anonymous function literal](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_dispatch) (as does
  [Taylor Wood above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50426394/1562315)) and
- includes a superfluous [`get`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get), which gives us a clue to the default
  `0` value.